# Linear Algebra SubSpace Test Example

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling to understand how to conduct a SubSpace test, one example that I have no clue how to do, is

> $V=\Bbb R^3$ and $W= \{(t,-t\sin(\pi/3),t\sqrt2): t\in\Bbb R\}.$

Can anyone explain to me how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given $s,t\in\Bbb R,$ is $$(s,-s\sin(\pi/3),s\sqrt2)+ (t,-t\sin(\pi/3),t\sqrt2)$$ an element of $W$? What about $$s (t,-t\sin(\pi/3),t\sqrt2)?$$ Can you show that $W$ is non-empty?

**Added Hint**: Another way to write the set $W$ is $$W=\biggl\{t\left(1,-\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt2\right):t\in\Bbb R\biggr\},$$ which you should be able to prove. The idea, then, is to show that if $\vec v,\vec w\in W,$ and if $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ then $\vec v+\vec w$ is a real scalar multiple of $\left(1,-\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt2\right),$ as is $\alpha\vec w.$ Showing that $W$ is non-empty should be trivial.

---

**Added**: I will walk you through the process of showing that $W$ is closed under addition. Showing that $W$ is non-empty should be easy, and showing that $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication will be similar to showing that it's closed under addition, so I leave both to you.

To show that $W$ is closed under addition, we must show that if $\vec v,\vec w\in W,$ then $\vec v+\vec w\in W.$

So, to start with, take any $\vec v,\vec w\in W.$ There are some questions that we need to ask ourselves along the way. For one thing, we need to ask ourselves: How can we show that $\vec v+\vec w\in W$? Well, by definition of $W,$ we must show that there is a real number $t$ such that $$\vec v+\vec w=\bigl(t,-\sin(\pi/3),t\sqrt2\bigr).\tag{$\star$}$$

Now we have a goal to shoot for! But before we go about finding some such $t$ to make $(\star)$ hold, we need to know a bit more about $\vec v$ and $\vec w.$ What can we say about them, except that they are vectors in $\Bbb R^3$? Well, so far, all we know is that (by hypothesis) they are elements of $W.$ Once again, we look to the definition of $W$ for more information, and we conclude that there are some real numbers $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $$\vec v=\bigl(t_1,-t_1\sin(\pi/3),t_1\sqrt2\bigr)\tag{1}$$ and  $$\vec w=\bigl(t_2,-t_2\sin(\pi/3),t_2\sqrt2\bigr).\tag{2}$$ Okay, now that we have an idea what $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ look like, we can figure out what $\vec v+\vec w$ looks like. Proceeding in much the same way as we did in the comments, we can show from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $$\vec v+\vec w=\bigl(t_1+t_2,-(t_1+t_2)\sin(\pi/3),(t_1+t_2)\sqrt2\bigr).\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ That's pretty much as simple as we can get it. Why would this be enough to conclude that $\vec v+\vec w\in W$? Well, don't forget our goal! We need to find some real number $t$ such that $(\star)$ holds. Ah, but $t_1$ and $t_2$ are both real numbers, so $t_1+t_2$ is *also* a real number. So, what happens to $(\star)$ when we let $t=t_1+t_2$? It becomes $(\heartsuit)$! We already know that $(\heartsuit)$ holds, and so $(\star)$ holds when $t=t_1+t_2$.Having found the desired $t,$ we can conclude that $\vec v+\vec w\in W,$ as desired. In fact, since we chose $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ to be *arbitrary* elements of $W,$ the argument above will work for *any* choice of $\vec v,\vec w\in W.$ So, at this point, we're done with the proof that $W$ is additively closed.

I suspect that the biggest reason that you were getting confused is because it  may have seemed that I was asking you to conclude  that the vector $$\bigl(s+t,-(s+t)\sin(\pi/3),(s+t)\sqrt2\bigr)$$ from our work was somehow the same thing as the vector $$\bigl(t,-t\sin(\pi/3),t\sqrt2\bigr)$$ from the definition of $W$. The kicker, here, is that these two vectors are using $t$ in a different way. The first is using $t$ as a *fixed but unspecified real value*, while the second is using $t$ as a *variable that ranges over all real numbers*. This seeming equivocation is rather confusing, especially to beginners. I, for one, remember being *terribly* confused by that when I was getting started, though at this point, such equivocation  passes by me without notice, since we could instead define $$W=\Bigl\{\bigl(r,-r\sin(\pi/3),r\sqrt2\bigr):r\in\Bbb R\Bigl\},$$ which eliminates the equivocation altogether! It is arguably sloppy of me to equivocate in this matter, but once one becomes accustomed to skipping this step and letting this worry go, one stops noticing it. Apologies for any confusion that may have caused.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I go about showing that

Comment: What *is* $(s,−s\sin(π/3),s \sqrt2)
+ (t,−t \sin(π/3),t \sqrt2),$ for example?

Comment: (s+t) + (-s sin(π/3) - tsin(π/3) + (s√2 + t√2)?

Comment: The expression you've typed above makes no sense, due to an extra "(". Even if you fixed that, though, you would have a real number, *not* an element of $\Bbb R^3$. Let's back it up further. What is $(a,b,c)+(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused

Comment: Do you know how to add two vectors in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Isn't is just, (a+x)+(b+y)+(c+z) ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That would once again be a real number. Rather, it should be $$(a+x,b+y,c+z).$$

Comment: Oh right, yeah I understand that, I think my notation was wrong rather than not understanding, but how do I use that to conduct a subspace test?

Comment: You try to find a way to rewrite both $$(s,−s\sin(π/3),s \sqrt2) + (t,−t \sin(π/3),t \sqrt2)$$ and $$s(t,−t \sin(π/3),t \sqrt2)$$ in the form of the elements of $W.$ So, now that we're speaking the same language (using the same notation), what is $$(s,−s\sin(π/3),s \sqrt2) + (t,−t \sin(π/3),t \sqrt2),
$$ for example?

Comment: That would be, (s+t, −s sin(π/3)-t sin(π/3),s√2 + t√2).

Comment: Great start! Simplify the second and third coordinates by factoring.

Comment: so that would make it, (s+t,-sin(π/3)(s+t),√2(s+t)). Now I know the fact that you have "s+t" in every expression, you use that to prove it is closed under addition, but I'm not quite sure exactly how to do that

Comment: Since $s$ and $t$ are real, what can you say about $s+t$? What can you then conclude, given the definition of $W$? Also, see my added hint.

Comment: It may also help you to rewrite it as $$\bigl(s+t,-(s+t)\sin(\pi/3),(s+t)\sqrt2\bigr),$$ instead.

Comment: That s+t is also real, so is that enough to show that it is closed under addition?

Comment: That is enough to show that the sum of two elements of $W$ is once again an element of $W,$ yes. Do you see why? If not, look at the definition of $W$ again. If that still doesn't help, let me know, and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: No sorry, I'm not completely sure as to why

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$(t, -t\sin(\pi/3), t\sqrt 2)=t(1, -1\sin(\pi/3), \sqrt 2)=t\mathbf{v}.$$ So $W$ consists of all multiples of a single nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$. This means **geometrically** that $W$ is a line though the origin and therefore it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Algebraically**, you can say that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication as follows:

1. take $x$ and $y$ in $W$, then $x=r\mathbf{v}$ and $y=s\mathbf{v}$ for some numbers $r, s$. Clearly, $x+y$ is also a multiple of $\mathbf{v}$ and hence in $W$. So, $W$ is closed under addition.
2. take $x$ in $W$, then $x=r\mathbf{v}$. Clearly, any scalar multiple of $x$ is a multiple of $\mathbf{v}$ and hence lies in $W$. So, $W$ is closed under scaling.

**Conclusion**: $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.